# Adding/removing product fields to Product class in Cartridge?

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway to add fields to the default product class provided by Cartridge? I'm attempting to setup a parent-child relationship where the parent is the Product class and the child embellishes with custom product fields.

Is this at all possible? Thanks.
Mark Anderson

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to subclass the product class, and then use your subclass instead anywhere you need access to the extra fields. Just bear in mind that spots that require the parent class will accept the subclass but spots that require the subclass will not accept the parent class. It's like putting a round peg into a square whole versus putting a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I realized there was a product_fieldsets variable that I could customize which brought in my customized fields.

Comment: Yeah, if you can find something to utilize on the actual model it's always better. That's why people still use user profiles in Django instead of subclassing `User` to add extra fields. The amount of work required to implement the subclass everywhere its needed would be daunting to say the least.